# How to migrate projects from one Jenkins server to another

Tags: jenkins

I currently have some Projects that are running on one Jenkins server. However recently we have set-up our own co-located Jenkins Server. Now the task is to migrate all the existing projects from the old Jenkins server to the new one. These are the same versions of Jenkins. What would be the easiest way to migrate these projects without using any plug-in ? The source code for all these projects in in SVN.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply copy the project directories from one machine to another. See the administration page in the [wiki](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Administering+Jenkins).